# Acceder a un elemento JsonArray que esta dentro de un JsonArray

Tags: java, android-studio, jsonobject, jsonarray

Tengo un JSONARRAY que tiene dentro otro JSONARRAY  , mi pregunta es como acceder a un elemento que esta en el segundo JsonArray y mostrarlo. He probado con:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        JSONArray jsonCards = data.getJSONArray("fundas");
        JSONArray tipos = jsonCards.getJSONArray(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonCards.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonCard = jsonCards.getJSONObject(i);
            tipos.getJSONObject(4);
```

Pero esto me devuelve el segundo elemento del jsonArray principal.

Mi json es el siguiente:

https://api.jsonbin.io/b/60204ee5d5aafc6431a54cc3

No se como poner json entero, por eso dejo un link.

Lo que yo quiero exactamente es mostrar el nombre de la funda, que en mi json es un array de fundas, y dentro de este array tengo un elemento que a su vez es un array tipos. de este array "tipos", quiero mostrar el elemento "imagen".

Comment: El JSON que has puesto no es válido. Pulsa en [edit], poniendo un JSON válido, aunque sea relativamente largo no importa. Y explica con más claridad lo que quieres. En el código veo que quieres acceder a los elementos directamente y también dentro de un bucle ¿? Ambas formas son válidas, pero delimita el problema, explicando si quieres acceder directamente a un determinado elemento o si quieres hacerlo desde el bucle. Otra cosa, los índices en arrays empiezan en `0`, de modo que si quieres acceder al segundo elemento, deberás usar el índice `1` no el ìndice `2`, que sería el tercer elemento.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que `jsonCards` es un array... debes recorrerlo para poder acceder a su `tipos`, ya que cada elemento tiene su propio array de tipos dentro

Comment: @ Benito-B Gracias por tu disponibilidad! ya he puesto el json en un link
Lo que quiero es mostrar el elemento "nombre" que esta dentro del array "fundas", y mostrar tambien el elemento "imagen" que esta dentro del arryar "tipos" que a su vez es un elemento del array "fundas".
Estoy trabajando en una app de android studio.

Comment: Pero, ¿cuál de los elementos? ¿uno en concreto, o quieres recorrer todos los elementos extrayendo los datos de esas claves que comentas?

Comment: El codigo que he puesto esta mal, porque me muestra todos los elementos de  `fundas`, y el elemento 2 de  `fundas`

Comment: No entiendo... ¿Qué es lo que quieres obtener realmente del JSON? No se sabe si es un elemento en concreto.

Comment: @ A. Cedano seria recorrer el array `fundas` y mostrar todos los valores del elemento `nombre`, y tambien mostrar todos los valores de `imagen` que contiene el array `tipos`

Answer (score 1):

Primero para dar solución a pregunta hay que analizar porque tu código falla, cuando realizas `jsonCards.getJSONArray(2);` a un Array lo que haces es solicitar el segundo elemento de del array, para obtener el `Objeto tipos` tienes que utilizar los métodos `getJSONObject("nombre")` `getJSONArray("nombre")` `getString("nombre")` para obtener la propiedad ó objeto que necesitas, no se puede utilizar la posición del nodo o propiedad en el `JSON` no se garantiza que la posición sea siempre la que espera, por ejemplo `nombre` que ocupa la segunda posición podría ocupar la  tercera si se agregara una nueva propiedad o si el servicio según la librería que utilice no siempre retorna el mismo orden, por eso se obtienen por el `nombre` del nodo.

Ahora analizando el JSON de ejemplo, hay varios problemas a tener en cuenta, porque el JSON varia el tipo de datos del nodo `tipos` he `imagen` a veces son un `JSONObject` y otras veces un `JSONArray`:

```
// tipos es un Array 
// he imagen un String
"-codmodelo":"ip7",
"nombre":"Iphone 7",
"tipos":[
   {
      "-codtipo":"ip7fagt",
      "descripcion":"Funda anti golpe PC + TPU",
      "precio":"10.00 €",
      "id":"2456456",
      "imagen":"https://ibb.co/Yh4Y5D7"
   }
]

// tipos es un Objeto que tiene un Array tipo, 
// he imagen un Objeto con una propiedad -ruta
"-codmodelo":"ip11prmx",
"nombre":"Iphone 11 Pro Max",
"tipos":{
   "tipo":[
      {
         "-codtipo":"ip11prmxfagT",
         "descripcion":"Funda anti golpe PC + TPU",
         "precio":"10.00€",
         "id":"2450003",
         "imagen":{
            "-ruta":"documentos/pic091.jpg"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

---

El código quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ProcesadorJSON {
    // Clase auxiliar que he creado para obtener el json,
    // remplazar por tu codigo.
    private static String jsonResponse = JsonObj.getJson;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        JSONArray fundas = data.getJSONArray("fundas");

        for (int i = 0; i < fundas.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject funda = fundas.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println("-codmodelo: " + funda.getString("-codmodelo"));
            System.out.println("nombre: " + funda.getString("nombre"));

            //Obtenemos un Objeto genérico con get para evaluar si tipos es un JSONObject o JSONArray
            Object objTipo = funda.get("tipos");

            if (objTipo instanceof JSONObject) {
                printTipos(((JSONObject) objTipo).getJSONArray("tipo"));
            } else if (objTipo instanceof JSONArray) {
                printTipos((JSONArray) objTipo);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printTipos(JSONArray tipos) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tipos.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject tipo = tipos.getJSONObject(i);
            printTipo(tipo);
        }
    }

    public static void printTipo(JSONObject tipo) {
        System.out.println("\t -codtipo: " + tipo.getString("-codtipo"));
        System.out.println("\t descripcion: " + tipo.getString("descripcion"));
        System.out.println("\t precio: " + tipo.getString("precio"));
        if (tipo.has("id")) {
            System.out.println("\t id: " + tipo.getString("id"));
        }

        //Obtenemos un Objeto generico para evaluar si imagen es un String o JSONObject
        Object objImagen = tipo.get("imagen");

        if (objImagen instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("\t ruta: " + objImagen.toString());
        } else if (objImagen instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject imagen = (JSONObject) objImagen;
            System.out.println("\t ruta: " + imagen.getString("-ruta"));
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es recorrer el array `fundas` y mostrar todos los valores del elemento `nombre`, y también mostrar todos los valores de `imagen` que contiene el array `tipos` puedes intentas el código de más abajo.

He puesto comentarios en cada parte explicando lo que se va haciendo. Cuando trabajas con JSON simplemente tienes que analizar la estructura del JSON y sacando cada elemento según dicha estructura y usando los métodos adecuados en cada caso.

Este sería el código:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        /*1. Obtienes el JSONArray que hay en fundas*/
        JSONArray jsonCards = data.getJSONArray("fundas");

        /*2. Recorres ese array*/
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonCards.length(); i++) {
            /*3. Obtienes cada JSONObject anidado en el array*/
            JSONObject jsonCard = jsonCards.getJSONObject(i);

            /*4. Obtienes el nombre, que es un String en el 1er nivel*/
            System.out.println(jsonCard.getString("nombre"));

            /*5. Obtienes el JSONArray que está en el JSONObject de la clave tipo*/
            JSONArray tipos = jsonCard.getJSONObject("tipo").getJSONArray("tipos");

            /*6. Recorres ese JSONArray para buscar la imagen*/
            for (int j = 0; j < tipos.length(); j++) {
                /*Nótese el uso del índice j aquí*/
                JSONObject jsonTipo=tipos.getJSONObject(j);
                /*7. imagen es a su vez un JSONObject, por eso hacemos esto*/
                JSONObject jsonImagen=jsonTipo.getJSONObject("imagen");
                /*8. Finalmente, obtenemos el dato, que es un String en la clave -ruta*/
                System.out.println(jsonImagen.getString("-ruta"));
            }
        }
```